# Date histogram filter

Tags: kibana

I using elk 5 , I created bar chart visualisation with date histogram aggregation, the problem is that when I filter, the visualisation filtered but I can not see the filter in the filter navbar.
Someone can help?

Comment: Time filters do not appear in the filter navbar. Time filters just set the application time to an absolute range. View the application time from the  timepicker widget in the upper right-hand corner

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I know the time picker but it's not exist in embedded iframe

Comment: That is a known issue, https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2739. There is a plugin that shows the time that can be used for embedded iframes, https://github.com/nreese/kibana-time-plugin

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Please mark the comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time filters do not appear in the filter navbar. Time filters just set the application time to an absolute range. View the application time from the timepicker widget in the upper right-hand corner.

The timepicker widget is not displayed in embedded iframes, https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2739. One work around for this issue is to use the plugin  https://github.com/nreese/kibana-time-plugin to show a timepicker for embedded iframes.